# Tried to run the html page but the output is now what I expected

Tags: html

I tried to run this page with the given input but it doesn't display any output instead it reloads and displays an empty result.[This is the given input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmeAr.png) [And this is the output which I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWc9J.png) . Below I have attached the code snippet.

```js
const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
const sentenceInputEl = document.querySelector('#sentence');
const letterInputEl = document.querySelector('#letter');

formEl.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const letterIndex = sentenceInputEl.value.indexOf(letterInputEl.value);
  if (letterIndex === -1 || letterInputEl.value === ''") {
    alert("The letter doesn't exist in the sentence");
  } else {
    const slicedWord = sentenceInputEl.value.slice(letterIndex + 1);
    alert(slicedWord);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="sentence">Sentence</label>
          <input type="text" name="sentence" id="sentence" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="letter">Letter</label>
          <input type="text" name="letter" id="letter" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The browser console is telling you about a syntax error which prevents your JavaScript code from executing.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.